# How can i set a button?

Tags: gridjs

Im table using gridjs first time and im newbie at js items. How can i set a button? and how can i get link it?

```js
        <script>
        new gridjs.Grid({
            columns: ["#ID", "Ürün Adı", "Ürün Durumu", "Marka", "Seri No", "Nerede",  "İşlem"],
            pagination: {
                limit: 7
            },
            sort: !0,
            search: !0,
            data: [
                [
                    "1",
                    "Iphone 13",
                    "Kullanımda",
                    "Apple",
                    "MN4564323",
                    "Yağız Savaş",
                    "button will be here, i need 2 buttons",
                ],
            ],
        }).render(document.getElementById("table-gridjs"));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You put it in columns array. Something like this.

```
<script>
    new gridjs.Grid({
        columns: ["#ID", "Ürün Adı", "Ürün Durumu", "Marka", "Seri No",  "Nerede",  "İşlem",{
            name: 'Buttons',
            formatter: (_, row) =>
                    gridjs.html(`<a href="#" onclick="save( '${row.cells[0].data}');" target="_blank">Example</a>`)
            
            }
```

],
pagination: {
limit: 7
},
sort: !0,
search: !0,
data: [
[
"1",
"Iphone 13",
"Kullanımda",
"Apple",
"MN4564323",
"Yağız Savaş",
"button will be here, i need 2 buttons",
],
],
}).render(document.getElementById("table-gridjs"));